# exception occurs when NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is used

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jdbc

When I use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, I get an exception `"No class Def Found Error"`.But when I use JdbcTemplate I don't get any exception.It works.The exception only happens when I use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/SpringProperties
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.<clinit>(StatementCreatorUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.getSqlType(BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(NamedParameterUtils.java:415)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:373)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:311)
    at com.harsh.spring.test.OffersDAO.update(OffersDAO.java:49)
    at com.harsh.spring.test.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.SpringProperties
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/SpringProperties - looks like you need the Spring Core jar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me the solution.It worked now.

Comment: just try reading the exception messages.  99% of the time, they are very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you include all your execution dependencies.  I suggest you consider some automated build tool with a declarative dependencies management.  For example maven could package your application with every transitive dependency you need just with the fragment you can find in http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @bob then you should mark as answer. it can useful to others

Comment: Thanks for giving me the solution.I downloaded the spring-core, spring context and spring-beans jar files.All the latest releases using  maven.It worked now.I downloaded the 4.0.2 release version.Before also i had this jar files.But they were not the latest version.But now i downloaded all the latest releases and it worked now.

Comment: I have less than 10 reputations.I have not been allowed to answer my own questions.I have to increase my reputations.I have only been allowed to add comments.

Answer (score 2):

Same Spring core version issue for me. I had this in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and was getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

I replaced that with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I use in maven `<spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>`,

Then I change to `<spring.version>4.0.2. RELEASE</spring>`. version, and now It's working well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.  What I did...in my eclipse>Project explorer>Project>Maven dependencies.  It showed me some 3.0.0 version of spring dependencies were included.  I simply right click all one by one select Maven from the options and then Exclude Maven Artifacts.  After that, I added all the spring 4.3.9 dependencies in pom.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have all these dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```